# How to find the quantiles of each variable of a data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lapply, summarize

I have a dataframe with multiple variables and I would like to find the quantiles () of each of these variables

Sample code:

```
testtable = data.frame(groupvar = c(rep('x',100), rep('y',100)), 
                       numericvar = rnorm(200))
```

I want to apply `quantile(., c(.05, .1, .25, .5, .75, .9, .95)`) to each of the variables in `testtable`. The ideal result would look like

```
   x    y
  .05 .05
  .1  .1
  .25 .25
  .5  .5
  .75 .75
  .9  .9
  .95 .95
```

where each entry is a quantile of `x` or `y`. For sample, `.05` is the 5th percentile of the `x` `.1` is the 10th percentile distribution of `x`, etc.

I tried `summarise` in `dplyr` but ran into a problem because my `quantile` function is returning a vector of length 7.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R solution where we `unstack` the data frame and calculating the quantile for each column, for each quantile, i.e.

```
sapply(unstack(testtable, numericvar ~ groupvar), function(i) quantile(i, v1))
```

which gives,

> ```
>               x           y
> 5%  -1.82980882 -1.49900735
> 10% -1.26047295 -1.02626933
> 25% -0.83928910 -0.68248217
> 50%  0.02757385 -0.02096953
> 75%  0.64842517  0.48624513
> 90%  1.63382801  1.09722178
> 95%  1.91104161  1.72846846
> ```

where `v1 <- c(0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.95)`

Comment: a tiny bit shorter: `sapply(unstack(testtable, numericvar ~ groupvar), quantile, probs = v1)`

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility with `lapply`, we need to convert first to `list`:

```
l <- split(testtable$numericvar, testtable$groupvar)
```

Now we can get the `quantile` then trasform back to `data.frame`:

```
ll <- lapply(l, function(x) quantile(unlist(x), c(.05, .1, .25, .5, .75, .9, .95)))
as.data.frame(ll)
#             x           y
# 5%  -1.8028162 -1.69293054
# 10% -1.3129427 -1.23125086
# 25% -0.7335853 -0.57010352
# 50% -0.1223181  0.05119533
# 75%  0.6727871  0.66203631
# 90%  1.3411195  1.08830220
# 95%  1.7068070  1.54248740
```

This could be turned in a function to call, you can add more to it to make it more general:

```
quantile_grouped <- function(data, group_var = "groupvar", quantile_var = "numericvar") {

  l <- split(testtable[, quantile_var], testtable[, group_var ])

  ll <- lapply(l, function(x) quantile(unlist(x), c(.05, .1, .25, .5, .75, .9, .95)))
  as.data.frame(ll)

}
quantile_grouped(testtable)
```

Comment: For your first line, you can avoid `lapply` by simply doing `split(testtable$numericvar, testtable$groupvar)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
pr <- c(0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.95)
as.data.frame.list(tapply(testtable$numericvar, testtable$groupvar,
                          quantile, probs = pr))
```

which gives:

> ```
>               x          y
> 5%  -1.57823487 -1.5142682
> 10% -1.28807795 -1.2153000
> 25% -0.60598752 -0.6889401
> 50% -0.07536852 -0.2036487
> 75%  0.57269482  0.4892494
> 90%  1.04087379  1.2231926
> 95%  1.22329927  1.7421848
> ```